# Proper way to implement AJAX request server-side in Node.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, heroku

I am building a search engine that queries the Twitter and Wiki APIs server-side after the client POSTs the search string.  When I was still completely client-side the AJAX request to the Wiki API looked like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
    data: {
        action: 'query',
        list: 'search',
        srsearch: searchString, // variable pulled from input
        format: 'json',
        //origin: 'https://www.mediawiki.org'
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp' // will probably use 'json' now that I'm server-side
}).done( function ( data ) {
    searchParser(data);
});
... //searchParser() below
```

Now, I have implemented a Node.js web app that takes the search string from a client-side form POST on the home page (*index.ejs*).  The server will then render the results page (*results.ejs*) with the wiki and twitter search results.  Twitter API search is already handled with [BoyCook's TwitterJSClient](https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient).

I would like to know the best way to perform this **exact** query from my server.  I have been looking around and cannot find a succinct answer.  Does anyone have any advice on this?

Comment: Node offers [`http.request()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) and [`http.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) for this.

Comment: Sure, but what about the dataType field and xhrFields field?

Comment: There is no build-in equivalent to `dataType`. You'll have to parse the response yourself -- [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). As for credentials, the `Authorization` header may be available, if the request from the client includes it -- and you'll have to copy it to this request. The browser won't have sent cookies related to `en.wikipedia.org` or `twitter.com` to your server.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  See final result below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came to based on [Jonathan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski) reply:

```
function wikiSearch () {

    var query = querystring.stringify({
        action: 'query',
        list: 'search',
        srsearch: searchString,
        srlimit: 10,
        srwhat: 'text',
        format: 'json'
    });
    var options = {
        hostname: 'en.wikipedia.org',
        path: '/w/api.php?' + query
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {

        if (!res) { 
            wikiData = "An error occured!";
            complete();
        };

        var body = '';
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        res.on('data', function(data) {
            body += data;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            wikiData = wikiDataParser( JSON.parse(body) );
            complete();
        });
    });

    req.end();
    req.on('error', function (err) {
        wikiData = "<h2>MediaWiki API is currently down.</h2>";
        complete();
    })

};
... // complete() is below
```

This changes the *wikiData* variable according to the request or response.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the MEAN stack. For starters, usually somebody has built a module you would install with NPM that would simplify connecting to the api. You could do it manually, but no point if an official release for node.js is available:

```
npm install twitter
```

below goes in your main express app file. It's simplified for example sake.

```
//include this....loads the twitter client api app...will make this a breeze
        var Twitter = require('twitter');

    //your access keys and info to login into the api....fill them.
        var client = new Twitter({
          consumer_key: '',
          consumer_secret: '',
          access_token_key: '',
          access_token_secret: ''
        });

    //the below code executes when you hit this path

    app.post('/getTweetsYo', function (res, req, data) {

// gets username from ajax post of user data....access via req.data. Passes it to twitter api request
        var params = {screen_name: req.data.username };
        client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response){
          if (!error) {
            console.log(tweets);

    // sending the tweets back to the front end!

    res.send(tweets);

          }
    });
```